# Scikit-Learn SVR Prediction Always Gives the Same Value

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, svm

I'm about to predict IMDB score (film rate) using Support Vector Regression in Scikit-Learn. The problem is it always gives the same prediction result for every input.

When i predict using data training, it gives various result. But when using data testing, it always gives the same value.

Data training prediction:

[image: Data training prediction]

Data testing prediction:

[image: Data testing prediction]

Here is the link for dataset: [IMDB 5000 Movie Dataset](https://web.archive.org/web/20170913202028/https://www.kaggle.com/deepmatrix/imdb-5000-movie-dataset)

My codes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sb
from sklearn import metrics as met


df = pd.read_csv("movie_metadata.csv")
df.head()


original = df.shape[0]
df = df.drop_duplicates(["movie_title"])
notDuplicated = df.shape[0]
df.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)
print(original, notDuplicated)


df["num_critic_for_reviews"].fillna(0, inplace = True)
df["num_critic_for_reviews"] = df["num_critic_for_reviews"].astype("int")

df["director_facebook_likes"].fillna(0, inplace = True)
df["director_facebook_likes"] = df["director_facebook_likes"].astype("int")

df["actor_3_facebook_likes"].fillna(0, inplace = True)
df["actor_3_facebook_likes"] = df["actor_3_facebook_likes"].astype(np.int64)

df["actor_2_facebook_likes"].fillna(0, inplace = True)
df["actor_2_facebook_likes"] = df["actor_2_facebook_likes"].astype(np.int64)

df["actor_1_facebook_likes"].fillna(0, inplace = True)
df["actor_1_facebook_likes"] = df["actor_1_facebook_likes"].astype(np.int64)

df["movie_facebook_likes"].fillna(0, inplace = True)
df["movie_facebook_likes"] = df["movie_facebook_likes"].astype(np.int64)

df["content_rating"].fillna("Not Rated", inplace = True)
df["content_rating"].replace('-', "Not Rated", inplace = True)
df["content_rating"] = df["content_rating"].astype("str")

df["imdb_score"].fillna(0.0, inplace = True)

df["title_year"].fillna(0, inplace = True)
df["title_year"].replace("NA", 0, inplace = True)
df["title_year"] = df["title_year"].astype("int")

df["genres"].fillna("", inplace = True)
df["genres"] = df["genres"].astype("str")


df2 = df[df["title_year"] >= 1980]
df2.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)

nRow = len(df2)
print("Number of data:", nRow)
nTrain = np.int64(np.floor(0.7 * nRow))
nTest = nRow - nTrain
print("Number of data training (70%):", nTrain, "\nNumber of data testing (30%):", nTest)

dataTraining = df2[0:nTrain]
dataTesting = df2[nTrain:nRow]
dataTraining.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)
dataTesting.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)


xTrain = dataTraining[["num_critic_for_reviews", "director_facebook_likes", "actor_3_facebook_likes", "actor_2_facebook_likes", "actor_1_facebook_likes", "movie_facebook_likes"]]
yTrain = dataTraining["imdb_score"]

xTest = dataTesting[["num_critic_for_reviews", "director_facebook_likes", "actor_3_facebook_likes", "actor_2_facebook_likes", "actor_1_facebook_likes", "movie_facebook_likes"]]
yTest = dataTesting["imdb_score"]

movieTitle = dataTesting["movie_title"].reset_index(drop = True)


from sklearn.svm import SVR

svrModel = SVR(kernel = "rbf", C = 1e3, gamma = 0.1, epsilon = 0.1)
svrModel.fit(xTrain,yTrain)


predicted = svrModel.predict(xTest)
[print(movieTitle[i], ":", predicted[i]) for i in range(10)]
```

Comment: I am seeming to have some similar problem with mine, always predicting exact same values for different input data.

Answer (score 6):

Change `gamma` from `0.1` to `1e-8` while keeping everything else the same.

When gamma is set to 0.1, the number of unique predictions is 8 and they're all close to 6.37. When gamma is set to 1e-8, 1366 unique predictions are outputted (xTest contains 1368 total samples).

Why does gamma matter?

> Intuitively, the gamma parameter defines how far the influence of a
>   single training example reaches, with low values meaning ‘far’ and
>   high values meaning ‘close’. The gamma parameters can be seen as the
>   inverse of the radius of influence of samples selected by the model as
>   support vectors.

There's a deeper explanation and example at [RBF SVM Parameters](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_rbf_parameters.html).

There's also a similar explanation here:
[Output of Scikit SVM in multiclass classification always gives same label](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125353/output-of-scikit-svm-in-multiclass-classification-always-gives-same-label)

Personally, I would use GridSearchCV at the bottom of your script instead. Here's an example for finding an ideal `gamma` an `C` value:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

#svrModel = SVR(kernel = "rbf", C = 1e3, gamma = 1e-8, epsilon = 0.1)
#svrModel.fit(xTrain,yTrain)


#predicted = svrModel.predict(xTest)
#[print(movieTitle[i], ":", predicted[i]) for i in range(10)]

#print('Unique predictions:', np.unique(predicted))

parameters = {
    "kernel": ["rbf"],
    "C": [1,10,10,100,1000],
    "gamma": [1e-8, 1e-7, 1e-6, 1e-5, 1e-4, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1]
    }

grid = GridSearchCV(SVR(), parameters, cv=5, verbose=2)
grid.fit(xTrain, yTrain)
```